# java.io.IOException: Unable to download JavaScript from 'http://localhost:19001/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js' (status 404)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.5

I know many will say this was answered on another thread, but I haven't found an answer to this problem. Either the thread is hijacked, or the fixes don't work.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1
Build #IU-145.258, built on March 17, 2016

My Project SDK is 1.8.0_73, Scala version is 2.11, and Play 2 version is 2.5.0.

I'm running my tests from the IDE by right clicking on the test folder of my project and click on Debug 'All Tests'. They all pass, but I get the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to download JavaScript from 'http://localhost:19001/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js' (status 404).
```

The IOException occurs in IntegrationSpec.scala. Can anyone help resolve this issue?

here are the files of my project.

Thanking you in advance

Francis

build.sbt

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `test` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws   , specs2 % Test )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

routes

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

Application.scala

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

main.scala.html

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

IntegrationSpec.scala

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

/**
 * add your integration spec here.
 * An integration test will fire up a whole play application in a real (or headless) browser
 */
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {

    "work from within a browser" in new WithBrowser {

      browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)

      browser.pageSource must contain("Your new application is ready.")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is jquery-1.9.0.min.js in your app directory?

Comment: Does the index page works correctly and finds jquery when running it locally?

Comment: Yes, if I run or debug the application, the page displays normally and finds jquery-1.9.0 as expected.

Comment: I realize now that your issue only appears when running the test from the IDE. I would like to help but I can't help you with that. Good luck.

Comment: I just encountered the same error and accidentially fixed it. I was running the tests via Intellij before and they failed with this exact problem. Then I ran them via the sbt command line (`sbt test`) to see if I get any helpful output - and that worked. No error. And after that the error vanished completely and everything runs fine even from the IDE. I can't reproduce the error anymore to figure out what was wrong. Maybe that's worth a shot, definitely an odd issue though.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I opened an issue on github (https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1111).  I tried the `set test` as @alextsc suggested but this did not resolve the issue in the IDE. Although running via the command line `set run` does allow the app to run.  (note: There's a strange "database needs evolution" error in the app itself.)